# A problem in the first-order predicate calculus.

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

So the teacher decided to make our life harder by giving us an extra-credit problem:

> Use the language of the first-order predicate calculus to express that in a group $ S $ of elements with a binary operation ‘$ \cdot $’, there exists only one identity element.

Considering that he didn’t even cover anything like this in class, I’m breaking my brains trying to figure it out. Can someone explain this one to me?

Comment: Well the existence part is easy: $\exists s \in S : \forall x \in S, s.x = x$--but this doesn't mean there can be _only_ one identity element.

Comment: I also want to make sure you understand that this isn't a proof.  You need to come up with a property which implies your statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formula is
$$
(\exists e)((\forall x)((x \cdot e = x) \land (e \cdot x = x)) \land (\forall f)((\forall x)((x \cdot f = x) \land (f \cdot x = x)) \Rightarrow (f = e))).
$$
You want to say that there exists an identity element, i.e., an element $ e $ such that $ x \cdot e = x $ and $ e \cdot x = x $ for all $ x $, and if $ f $ is any other element satisfying the same two properties, then $ f = e $.